# Where should I look into for the error "MalformedResponse Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Got the error

> MalformedResponse Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response

had read [Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response for Ssml response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937971) but still did not get the point.

I'm quite a newbie.

Tried to follow the code provided in "Query Data Scalably for Actions on Google using Cloud Firestore", but got the error.

```
//Copyright 2018 Google LLC.SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

'use strict';

const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const collectionRef = db.collection('restaurants');

app.intent('ask_recipe_intent', (conv, {name}) => {
  const term = name.toLowerCase();
  const termRef = collectionRef.doc(`${term}`);

  return termRef.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const {city, name} = snapshot.data();
      conv.ask(`Here you go, ${name}, ${city}. ` +
            `What else do you want to know?`);

    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log('error:', e);
      conv.close('Sorry, try again and tell me another food.');
    });
});


exports.actionsOracle = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I'm trying to understand what

```
`${term}`
```

is and how this is used in Firebase? I don't have any document named "term".

Comment: What is (`${term}`) ? I don't have any document in Firebase collection called "term", how this is used in Firebase Document?

Comment: Please don't add code in comments - it makes it more difficult to understand what your question is. Go ahead and edit the question if you are trying to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: @Prisoner My question is, where should I look into the error message as title? I'm guessing ${term} should be the problem since I copied the code but don't really understand what this mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few unrelated questions here.

The line

```
collectionRef.doc(`${term}`);
```

is overly complex. You can safely rewrite it as

```
collectionRef.doc(term);
```

since the backtick-quote doesn't do anything in this case. Backtick quotes in recent versions of JavaScript do expression expansion inside the `${}` part. So evaluating the expression

```
`${term}`
```

just evaluates to whatever `term` is. So the result of that function is to create a reference to a document in Firestore named by `term`, which is just the lowercase version of the `name` parameter from your Dialogflow Intent.

Which leads us to the error you're getting. That typically happens if you fail to send a reply. Failing to send a reply can happen for a number of reasons, the two most common being

- You didn't call `conv.ask()` or `conv.close()`
- You are doing an asynchronous operation (such as calling a database) without returning a Promise

However, in your case, it looks like you're doing both.

It seems possible that your function is generating an error before it reaches the database call. The most likely possibility in this case might be the line

```
const term = name.toLowerCase();
```

which could be causing an error if `name` isn't defined, meaning it wasn't a parameter in the Dialogflow Intent.

You may wish to consult the following two articles which also look into debugging Actions on Google Intent fulfillments:

- [Debugging Common Actions on Google Errors](https://medium.com/google-developers/debugging-common-actions-on-google-errors-7c8527378d27)
- [Hey Google, I Need Help With My Action](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d)

Comment: Thanks for the detail instruction.  I had tried to figure out but only got a better error..."Sorry, try again and tell me another food." which is  the error for conv.close.   `name` is defined in Dialogflow, and a "name" field is created in Firestore.  Any suggestion?   [link]http://johocen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Dialogflow.jpg

Comment: Finally I had figured it out after created a document in Firestore with the same "name".  Really appreciate your help, if there is anything I can be of help, please feel free to tell me, I'm retired with plenty of time available.